# How does an "Invoice" table look like in a professional database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am creating a .NET bookkeeping  application, and thought that it could be a good idea hearing from others how my database tables should look like.

I have a "product" and  an "invoice" table and some other tables irrelevant to my question.

Outside computer languages, an invoice has several products most of the time.

Should I create a bridge table "invoiceProduct" with InvoiceId and ProductId columns?
 Or should I just add an arbitrary number of columns to my "invoice" table with a name format like: "product1", "product2"... Until reaching some limit?

Comment: Definitely the former, create a bridge table.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idiom is to have a parent **Invoices** table with a child **InvoiceItems** table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
    invoice_number  INT,
    customer_id     INT    REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
    purchase_date   DATE,
    -- other fields go here,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_number)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice_items
(
    invoice_number   INT   REFERENCES invoices (invoice_number),
    line_number      INT,
    product_id       INT   REFERENCES products (product_id),
    quantity         INT,
    -- more fields,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_number, line_number)
);
```

Note this is a generic pseudoSQL which will need to be edited for your particular platform, and that my choice of `INT` for most of the fields is purely arbitrary.